# Continuous but not uniformly continuous in $\text{GL}(2,\Bbb{C})$

Tags: group-theory, complex-analysis, lie-groups

Essentially, I'm trying to find an example of a function that is continuous but not uniformly continuous on $\text{GL}(2,\Bbb{C})$.  I'm aware that this group is isomorphic (up to constant multiples) to the Möbius transformations.  So I'm having a go at developing some geometric intuition there.  However, as my prior inquiries indicate, my epsilon-delta skills are lacking.  Hence, I find these sorts of examples tough to fabricate.

Edit:  Norm is the boring Euclidean one on $\Bbb{C}^4$.

Comment: What metric do you put on GL(2,C)?

Comment: @t.b. Apologies!  The boring one.  Euclidean Norm...viewing it as a vector in C^4...

Comment: So, how about devising a non-uniformly continuous function on $\mathbb{C}^4$ first, then?

Comment: @t.b.  This was my approach...struggle still medoes...

Comment: Well, what's a function on $\mathbf R$ that isn't uniformly continuous? Let's start small.

Comment: What @Dylan said...

Comment: @DylanMoreland x^2 seems pretty cool.

Comment: @t.b. (didn't want you to miss out on the sweet action)

Comment: Next step: embed an unbounded part of $\mathbf{R}$ isometrically into $GL(2,\mathbf{C})$ and devise a function on $GL(2,\mathbf{C})$ that restricts to $x^2$ on that embedded copy.

Comment: @t.b. and I'm lost...

Comment: Try $A \mapsto (\det{A})^2$ and the embedding $t \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} t & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, for $t \neq 0$, for example...

Comment: @t.b. Ah, much thanks! Apologies for my lack of mental fortitude. And one last question...I know that det is discontinuous over R.  Can you briefly remind me why C fixes things?

Comment: You must be confusing some things and misremember... You can't get much more continuous than being a polynomial in the entries.

Comment: @t.b. oops.  path-connectedness.  that's enough failures for 1 night.

Comment: I suggest that you try to concoct a few more examples and post them as an answer. Then ping me and I'll have a look.